# Electromagnetic interference in a Car

Tags: electromagnetism, inverter

I am currently working with a 12 volt inverter to power EL tape. The tape is wired in various places in my vehicle, I have tested it in my car and I hear a high pitched noise on my radio when I try to use the Aux port on the radio so I know it is causing mild interference but will it cause and damage to the other aspects of the vehicle such as power steering or Dash display? If so how would I reduce or shield the components from the inverter

Comment: Is your power steering electronic? For that matter, is your dash display electronic?

Comment: What is EL tape?

Comment: ElectroLuminescense stuff: http://electroluminescence-inc.com/ELsheets.htm 100V @ 1-3 kHz, EMC issues disguised as a display backlight...

Comment: Yes my dash has a nice LCD display and my power steering is electronic;